# How to test hypothesis that a change in x is associated with a change in y in a repeated measures context

Tags: lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have a dataset with six variables:

- **perceived_risk**: the perceived risk of getting a disease on a scale
  from 1-5.
- **interest_in_screening**: the subject's interest in being
  screened for the disease on a scale from 1 to 5
- **age_group**
- **sex**
- **time**: 0 or 1 - Each person was asked about risk and interest at two time points
- **person_id**

The outcome is **interest_in_screening** and the primary explanatory variable I am interested in is **perceived_risk**.

I want to test two hypotheses.

1. Perceived risk is positively associated with interest in screening (Patients with a higher perceived risk also tend to have a greater interest in being screened)
2. Changes in perceived risk are positively associated with changes in screening interest (Patients with larger increases in perceived risk over time also have larger increases in screening interest over time.) This seems like a hard one to me.

The answers to these question should adjust for differences in age and sex and take into account the repeated measures design.

I have a few questions:

- Is it possible to test these using a linear mixed model with a random patient intercept? If so how? (possibly using the lme4 package in R)
- Are the two hypotheses I want to test actually the same or are they different?
- How bad is it to model the likert scale (1-5) outcome as a continuous normal random variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to specify the model? Probably not on topic for this site, but the model for cross-sectional associations would be `lmer(risk ~ interest + age + sex + (1|id))`. and for change, the ANCOVA: `lmer(risk1 ~ interest1 + age + sex + risk0)` since you don't have multiple post baseline measures and you're interested in change, there's no dependent data by design.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a simple correlation test, e.g. using spearmans or Pearsons correlation coefficient.

The R code would be:

```
cor.test(x, y)
```

When testing for (1) you are simultaneously testing for (2) and vice versa, the hypotheses are the same. 
You can visualize this by taking the extreme case, i.e. *y* is 100% correlated with *x*. If the drawn *x* stems for the upper 95 percentile of the x-distribution, then you immediately know that the *y* will be in the upper 95 percentile of the *y* distribution.

As for how this approach is justified, well, you question is whether two variables are correlated. Therefore you calculate the correlation coefficient and test whether this coefficient is significant. 
The approach obviously only work in case you're only interested in the pairwise correlation of two variables, e.g. *interest_in_screening* and *perceived_risk*.

If you want to check for all predictors simultaneously you can indeed use a mixture model and then check the slope for significance. 
You can also encode the outcome 1-5 as a continuously normal variable, since these stages have the same implied ordering.

Comment: Maybe you can include a couple sentences defending this approach in spite of the dependent data that results from repeated measures?

Comment: I didn't read your full question, sorry about that. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks @bi_scholar. Your approach is very simple and straightforward and I like your explanation that (1) and (2) are the same. So it seems like you are not concerned about accounting for the repeated measures or treating a likert scale measurement as continuous and normally distributed. I wonder if others agree?